# Unable to unassign the category of a product in backend magento 2

Tags: product, admin, category, magento2.2.6, save

I wish to unassign the categories of a product in admin end. After unassigned the categories, I have saved the product. But the saved changes is not applied. Please provide me a solution to solve this

Comment: Go to that category and remove that product from product assigned tab @Jaisa

Comment: Please check your log file

Comment: Log throws only the catch invalidate msg'

Answer (score 0):

Run following commands:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
rm -rf  var/cache/* var/page_cache/* generated/*
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried do this but still same, its still not appearing it has been a day but the changes of product assign unassign still not reflecting

Comment: perform this command on all servers.